# Disable Typed Parameters for JavaScript in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, javascript

This question is about the PhpStorm IDE.
I know I'm not on Jetbrains, but I could not get any help there, neither in their support forums. As WP is written in PHP, I thought of posting my question here, as there are also potentially others with this problem:

When I [change the signature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/change-signature.html#changing-function-signature) of a js function that has type information in its JsDoc; like for example:

```
/**
 * @param {string} word - Word used as the greeting
 */

function sayHi( word ){ console.log(word); }
```

And then apply the signature refactoring to change for example just the name, what I get is:

```
/**
 * @param {string} word - Word used as the greeting
 */

function sayHiThere( word :string ){ console.log(word); }
```

I've spent two hours now also on trying to get rid of this problem on my own without success. All I could find out is that, if you specify the types of your function parameters, PHPStorm automatically adds that type to your function signature in case of a signature refactoring; turning your signatures and thus actually your entire code into invalid javascript! How can the automatic addition of in this case `:string` be turned off, while still being able to use the `{string}` documentation in the `@param` line?

Comment: This has nothing to with WordPress, and will be closed for that reason. It *might* work over on [so], but I'm not positive. That said, type annotation in native JS are only a proposal at this point - I'm not aware of any implementations which currently support that syntax. That sort of type hint is usually associated with TypeScript functionality - you might check through the settings for any sort of TypeScript options. Some editors provide type hints like that directly in JavaScript without explicitly leveraging TypeScript - but usually they're just UI and not actually inserted into the code.

Comment: I know it's not tied to WP, but definitely to experienced PHP/Js devs, hence I thought of WP and hoped getting some help here. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the understanding :) . I hope you get it sorted out - that is a proper annoying problem :/

Comment: Still added my current solution; just in case...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone with the same problem faces this question; the best solution I've currently [found](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-jsdoc-comments.html#ws_js_jsdoc_typescript_syntax) is the use of the `@type` doc tag instead, so you would write something like:

```
/**
 * @param word - Word used as the greeting
 * @return {void}
 * @type {(word : string) => void}
 */

function sayHiThere( word ){ console.log(word); }
```

When refactoring the signature, this at least does not provide the types to the function parameters, while it shows the types of the function when you start typing the function's name to call it (so when you start typing `sayH`, a dialogue like this shows up: `function(string):mixed`, but the data types do not show up when you provide the parameters themselves.